# some of session varibles gets back to the old value

Tags: php, arrays, session

i use centos 6.6, php 5.3.4

I have a php script called in an iframe(let's call it a.php).. 
when it's called as a.php?p_type=1&item_num=1234, 
it saves an array into session.
sometimes, it merges two array in session and save it into session again
but the merging doesnt work..
here is the simplified code.
(i will hide minor details for brevity)

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"'); 
session_start(); 

$p_type_val = $_GET["p_type"];
$sess_var = "a".$p_type_val;
$some_array = $_SESSION[$sess_var];
if(isset($_GET["item_num"])
{
    $some_array[] = $_GET["item_num"];
    $_SESSION[$sess_var] = $some_array;
}

if($p_type_val == 1)   // when p_type is 1, merge two arrays in the session.
{
    $sess_var2 = "a"."2";

    $some_array2 = $_SESSION[$sess_var2]; 

    $_SESSION[$sess_var2] = array_merge($some_array,$some_array2);
}

else if($p_type_val == 2)
{
    $some_array2 = $_SESSION["p2"];
    print_r($some_array2);
}
```

.........

first, i called a.php?p_type=1&item_num=1234, then i called a.php?p_type=2 lator,
then the newly added item number 1234 to "a2" is lost. the values in the array "a2" is back to the old values.
but the values in "a1" are no problem.

i checked the session file in /var/lib/php/session directory and found all the result is as i expected. 
after i called a.php?p_type=1, the values in the file are as i expected.
but right after a.php?p_type=2, the values go back to the old ones.

the funny thing is when i call a.php?p_type=2 twice with diffrent item_nums,
the array "a2" works correctly.

i don't know why the some values in a session go back to old values.
where should i start debugging for this..

any suggestion would be appreciated..

Comment: In what moment you define the ´$_SESSION[$ses_var]´ please show that script too, also in this line $some_array[] = $_GET["item_num"]; change 'some_array[]' for '$some_array()' because the '[]' is for call a specific position in the indexer, the '()' by the other hand, sort it automaticly, which, it seems, is what you are trying to do here (in that part of the code, at least).

Comment: it's simplified code for explanation coz the real code is very long. and the code above, $_SESSION[$sess_var] is defined in if clause. in this way, there have been no problem for a  long time. and [] in an array means new index next the the last. i thought it's no problem also. this is an old code with no problem. but i have to merge two array in session now. that's where the problem shows up

Answer (score 0):

i guess your problem is you don't read the manual about it, no rudeness intended but it clearly say there than when you merge two arrays that can happend, explain also the 'whys' of it, because of that i suggest you read the stuff entirely, no kittin, there is some overlapping examples explained in the section of examples of the manual too, and explain how to avoid/use that "problem".

it textualy says:
  "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."

So, probably you are using the same string values in both $_SESSION variables, or both of them have the same int to index data, i told you, it is necesary to see the creation of the $_SESSION, otherwise i cant see the compositions of that arrays that you are merging and, because of that, i can't suggest one way to solve the problem oriented to your necesitys.

which, in fact, you are not saying, you are merging two $_SESSION variables but not saying why is that for, and taking that in perspective, the rest of the people cannot even know if that is the right aproach for what you want.

Anyway, your solution is to read that part of the manual & instanciate that to your code.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Have a good day